# Disable doublespacing in multi-line header

Tags: header-footer, line-spacing

In my latex file, I am including a multi-line header through:

```
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\AtPageUpperLeft{%
\makebox(480,-70)[r]{\resizebox{380pt}{!}{%%
\textsf{\textbf{\color{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
     Author:         & \authorname\\
     Title:          & \title\\
     Date:           & {\today}      
\end{tabular}
```

And later in the document, I am using

```
\doublespacing
```

to have double spacing in the document. However, this command also affects the multi-line header and results in double spacing in the header as well. This looks bad. How can I achieve double spacing in the document but NOT in the multi-line header?

Comment: Can you give us mor information in form of a [compilable minimal example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html)?

Comment: Yes, please give a minimal example, but can't you just put `\singlespacing` inside the code fragment you posted?

Comment: This code is missing 6 (six!) right braces. At least include the whole command. Also, `\title` is used in a nonstandard way, so this wouldn't work without some nonstandard class or package. That said, you can use a `\savebox` to store the `\makebox` material while single spacing is in effect, then just use that box.

Answer (score 2):

The `fancyhdr` package is immune to this problem. It might also be an easier option for creating your multi-line header.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\doublespacing
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\begin{tabular}{rl}
     Author:         & author\\
     Title:          & tile\\
     Date:           & date      
\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Gives the output:

[image: output]

If you don't want the line under the header, you can `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`

Comment: That is a good option. However, I want the multi-line header to be placed above the fancyhdr. My document already has a fancyhrd with page numbers, titles etc. What I need is another header on top of that which provides details on title, author and date of the document.